# All my requests are returning a 404 error (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm not sure if its a server issue or something im missing in my routes but all my routes are returning with a 404 error for example

```
POST https://enigmatic-cliffs-10818.herokuapp.com/api/user/addFavorite/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

```
POST https://enigmatic-cliffs-10818.herokuapp.com/api/user/register 404 (Not Found)
```

I only have routes including users - login and register, and one to add favourites to their account.

I have come across this error multiple times and i cant seem to change it

here is my github repo would appreciate any help!
https://github.com/MarketingPlus/Tipsy

I am using axios to post my requests aswell

for example here:

```
    register( userData ) {
      console.log("------");
      console.log(userData);
      console.log("------");

        return this.axios.post("/api/user/register", userData);

    }
```

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

try to add the line below on your package.json

```
"proxy" : "https://enigmatic-cliffs-10818.herokuapp.com/"
```